# Swagger Annotation Object

Tags: java, annotations, swagger

When I read the [Swagger Annotations apidocs](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/index.html), I just find that some annotations are not for class or method just like `@Info` and `@Contact`.  
For example, the description of `@Info` is "High-level metadata for a Swagger definition ". Is it just an annotation object? How to use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the data your swagger definition includes, you can do so with the following:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(
        info = @Info(
                description = "My API",
                version = "V1.2.3",
                title = "The only API you'll ever need to learn about me",
                termsOfService = "share and care",
                contact = @Contact(name = "Sponge-Bob", email = "sponge-bob@swagger.io", url = "http://swagger.io"),
                license = @License(name = "Apache 2.0", url = "http://www.apache.org"),

        consumes = {"application/json" },
        produces = {"application/json" },
        schemes = {SwaggerDefinition.Scheme.HTTP, SwaggerDefinition.Scheme.HTTPS},
        externalDocs = @ExternalDocs(value = "About me", url = "http://about.me/me")
)
public interface MyApiDefinition {}
```

Source: https://swagger.io/blog/customizing-your-auto-generated-swagger-definitions-in-1-5-x/

From the [Wiki](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#swagger-definition):

> The SwaggerDefinition annotation provides properties corresponding to
>   many (but not all) top-level properties of the Swagger object,
>   allowing you to set these for your auto-generated definition. The
>   annotation can be on any class scanned during the Swagger
>   auto-configuration process, i.e. it does not have to be on a JAX-RS
>   API class but could just be on a marker/config interface